# how git get the cppcheck report

Tags: git, cppcheck

Firstly, `Cppcheck` checks code will come out a result which stored in a file.

In `Git`, the `file` is in everyone's local computer because Git is a distributed system,

Now we want to collect the files and analyze the files. But we don't know how to collect

we do not want to  push 'the file' to the server, this would be too complicated

and we also do not want to ask everyone to send their files to me.

Then how to collect the `files` by a easy way?

Comment: The question is not very clear. What are you trying to do? Also note, that the choice of version control system is orthogonal to choice of a static checker; they don't interact with each other. At all.

Comment: Git is a distributed system, but you do have a central repository, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what does the orthogonal choice mean, do you mean you have another good static checker? Yes, we have a central repo, but we can't let everyone to push the file on the repo, that would be inefficiency.

Comment: Orthogonal means they don't affect each other. It is totally irrelevant to your static checker workflow whether you are using git or subversion or cvs or clearcase or whatever. And you didn't describe the workflow, so there is really nothing that can be answered. (Note: questions can be edited and should be when providing further details)

Comment: Thank you for your advice Jan. I have edited my question, maybe now it is more clear!

Comment: No, it's not clearer. You still didn't explain what is your ultimate goal with this.